# ¿Como solucionar error en migración de laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Estoy intentando crear una migración para una tabla llamada "Clientes" pero al querer crear una clave foranea en la tabla obtengo un error que no se como solucioinar.

```
Schema::create('clientes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('codigo');
        $table->boolean('estado')->default(0);
        $table->string('dpi',50);
        $table->string('nombres',255);
        $table->string('apellidos',255);
        $table->date('fecha_nacimiento');
        $table->string('genero',50);
        $table->string('telefono',50);
        $table->string('correo_electronico',255);
        $table->string('direccion',100);
        $table->foreignId('ubicacion')
        ->constrained('tb_barrio_caserio_finca_aldea','codigo')
        ->onUpdate('cascade')
        ->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->string('cuenta_bancaria',50);
        $table->string('enlace_facebook',255);
        $table->string('enlace_instagram',255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Acá esta la estructura de mi tabla y cuando ejecuto el comando

```
php artisan migrate
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `bdfinanssoreal`.`clientes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `clientes` add constraint `clientes_ubicacion_foreign` foreign key (`ubicacion`) references `tb_barrio_caserio_finca_aldea` (`codigo`))
```

Comment: Si la tabla ya fue creada, pero las cree con el gestor que tengo, las tengo que migrar desde laravel? lo que pasa es que esas tablas no tendrán ningún tipo de interactividad en el sistema, solo es información de rrelleno.

Comment: La clave primaria es int(11) porque la cree desde el gestor pero no se que tipo de datos implementa laravel para las claves foraneas utilizando el auxiliar foreingId()

Comment: Actualmente el proyecto esta sobre la version Laravel 8.33.1

Comment: Estuve leyendo la documentación mientras esperaba alguna respuesta y todo apunta a que tienes razón, hice las migraciones de esas tablas desde laravel y no desde el gestor para que todo tuviera armonía y volví a crear mi modelo y mi migración de Clientes y funcionó bien, puedes dejar tu respuesta para dar la verifiación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se origina por la llave primaria de tu tabla: `tb_barrio_caserio_finca_aldea` ya que como expusiste en los comentarios el tipo de dato de la misma es un `int(11)`.

Lo anterior, debido a que en versiones recientes de Laravel de *manera predeterminada* se maneja el tipo de dato `bigint` por medio del método `unsignedBigInteger`.

Esto te lo menciono por que para crear tu llave foránea estas usando el método [`foreignId`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId) que es un *alias* del método mencionado anteriormente.

De hecho si te diriges a esta ubicación:

```
tuApp\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\BluePrint.php
```

Notarás que la instancia de la clase `ForeignIdColumnDefinition` en el método `foreignId().....` tiene como segundo argumento un array de configuración con valores relevantes tales como:

- Tipo => `bigInteger`
- auto increment => `false`
- unsigned => `true`
- etc

Entonces:

- Ambos tipos de datos que manejes en tus llaves deben empatar
- Ya sea que explícitamente indiques al declarar la llave foránea que el tipo de dato sea [un entero sin signo](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-unsignedInteger)
- O (cuidando siempre pensando en preservar tus datos) que hagas un `ALTER....` para pasar la llave primaria a un entero grande

Comment: Excelente, esto solucionó mi error.